# Disabling input to an existing x11 window

Tags: linux, x11, window-managers

Is it possible to disable input to an already existing x11 window? In the following Stack Overflow question [How to prevent an X Window from receiving user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835922/how-to-prevent-an-x-window-from-receiving-user-input) it is suggested that it might be possible to do this with xprop but I don't really understand what the xprop input is supposed to be.

Using xprop I also notice there is a window property called WM_TAKE_FOCUS that perhaps can be deleted somehow? Is there not a x11 api call to disable all input equivalent to the Windows api call EnableWindow which disables all input?

Edit:
Tried deleting WM_TAKE_FOCUS, doesn't seem to change anything sadly..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a certain window to ignore mouse and keyboard input regardless of how the window is actually meant to be used. I managed to disable keyboard input but not mouse input so far.

Comment: Open an InputOnly window as a child of your specific window. You may have to keep it above other children by monitoring SubstructureNotifyMask events.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a window that doesn't hijack the keyboard. Let's simplify this using a command with options.

```
open my.pdf -no_input
```

A process that maintains control of the input device after opening a window, **regardless** of focus.